# Unable to send mail in my site

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I have a contact form in my site.I would like to receive the mail from the visitors by that form. But the strange is my code is not working. I have some validation part in my site.The Page gets Refresh,But not receiving any mail.Could anybody help me to solve this issue.

My HTML code is

```
<form novalidate name="contacto" method="post" action="" class="form_contacto" id="formContacto">
    <fieldset>
                                                <label for="idEmpresa">
            <span>Company</span>
            <input type="text" name="comp" id="idEmpresa" placeholder="Company" value="">
                        </label>

        <label for="idContacto">
            <span>Name and surname/s</span>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="idContacto" placeholder="Name and surname/s" value="">
                        </label>

        <label for="idEmail">
            <span>E-mail</span>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="idEmail" placeholder="E-mail" value="">
                        </label>

        <label for="idTelefono">
            <span>Telephone number</span>
            <input type="tel" name="telephone" id="idTelefono" placeholder="Telephone number" value="">
                        </label>

        <label for="idConsulta">
            <span>Any remarks?</span>
            <textarea name="message" id="idConsulta" rows="3" placeholder="Any remarks?"></textarea>
                        </label>



    <input type="submit" class="send" name="form_contacto" value="send" >

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <input type="hidden" name="control" value="Este campo no debe rellenarse">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_content" value="12">
        <input type="hidden" name="h1" value="Contact">
        <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="en">
        <input type="hidden" name="redir" value="/en/contact/">
        <input type="hidden" name="plantilla" value="contacto">
        <input type="hidden" name="referer" value="">

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

My PHP code is

```
    <?php
 $msg="";
if(isset($_POST['form_contacto']))
{
print_r($_POST['form_contacto']);

$comp=$_POST['name'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['telephone'];

$detail=$_POST['message'];

require("class.phpmailer.php"); // path to the PHPMailer class

$mail = new PHPMailer();  

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "xxx@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "sunnight"; // SMTP password 

$mail->From     = "$email";
$mail->AddAddress("yyy@gmail.com");  

$mail->Subject  = "quote from $email";
$mail->Body     = "$detail";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;  


if(!$mail->Send()) {


echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
$msg="<p style=\"color:#99CC00; font-size:13px;\">your registration was Successfull!.</p>";

}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried some standard mail with your webspace? Have you checked your hoster does allow you to send mail with php?

Comment: my hosting machine allows to use php mailer..i have implemented it in my older pages...

Comment: Try to `print_r($_POST[]);`, what it returns?

Comment: After echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo; add exit; Then add that error message to your question

Comment: I get the Error like "Send Mailer error:SMTP Connect failed();"

Answer (score 0):

You have a minor error in your code.

In form tag the name is "contacto" and in submit tag its "form_contacto". So give them same name and it will work i think.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the connection prefix from the host to `SMTPSecure`.

In your case:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

Have look at this example: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebgmail (don't be confused, they are using TLS instead of SSL but both is working with gmail)

Comment: Nope. That is valid syntax in PHPMailer.

Comment: That's also an obsolete link - PHPMailer has not been maintained on worxware for years.

Answer (score 0):

This error is covered very thoroughly [in the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). You are using an old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on an old example. I suggest you start again with an up-to-date one, specifically [this one](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps).

Do not set the `From` address to be the email address of the person submitting the form - it will fail to send if you're using gmail or yahoo (and others) and is likely to be rejected elsewhere for any domain that has set up SPF correctly. Do this instead:

```
$mail->setFrom('xxx@gmail.com'); //Use your own gmail address
$mail->addReplyTo($email);
```

The syntax you have used for the `Host` value is valid (though ssl on port 465 has been deprecated for 15 years!). You can set values for `Host`, `SMTPSecure` and `Port` properties all in one go, like this:

```
$mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com:587';
```